# How to count specific characters in a list for each string separately

Tags: python, string, list, count, char

as i title says. I think code will describe what i want to do.

input:

```
words = ['oko', 'grzybobranie', 'żółw', 'jaźń', 'zażółcone krzewy', 'hipodrom', 'szczęki', 'kurs poprawkowy']
```

expected output:

```
sum of polish signs in words - [0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0]
```

My work:

```
words = ['oko', 'grzybobranie', 'żółw', 'jaźń', 'zażółcone krzewy', 'hipodrom', 'szczęki', 'kurs poprawkowy']
sumOfChars = [len(i) for i in words]
polish = 'ą ć ę ł ń ó ś ź ż'.split()
lista = []
for i in words:
    for x in i:
        if x in polish:
            lista.append(x)
print(sumOfChars)
print(lista)
```

And my output:

```
[3, 12, 4, 4, 16, 8, 7, 15]
# ^ sum of chars in every string
['ż', 'ó', 'ł', 'ź', 'ń', 'ż', 'ó', 'ł', 'ę']
# ^ special signs in my strings
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list for each word and count the length of each sublist. I've updated your code accordingly:

```
words = ['oko', 'grzybobranie', 'żółw', 'jaźń', 'zażółcone krzewy', 'hipodrom', 'szczęki', 'kurs poprawkowy']
sumOfChars = [len(i) for i in words]
polish = 'ą ć ę ł ń ó ś ź ż'.split()
lista = []
for i in words:
    tmp = []
    for x in i:
        if x in polish:
            tmp.append(x)
    lista.append(tmp)
print(sumOfChars)
print(lista)
print([len(l) for l in lista])
```

Comment: Thank you kind man, now am just about to count them which i can do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple list comprehension:

```py
words = ['oko', 'grzybobranie', 'żółw', 'jaźń', 'zażółcone krzewy', 'hipodrom', 'szczęki', 'kurs poprawkowy']
polish = 'ąćęłńóśźż'

output = [sum(j in polish for j in i) for i in words]
```

Output:

```py
[0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Well i am always shocked about one-line mans hah. Thank You!